# Replace Row with Multiple Other Rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm looking for a way to replace a resulting row with other values if a certain criteria is met. For Example, if the result is:

```
Dog
Cat
Mouse
Bear
```

And within Cat there is 1-2-3-4, I would like the result to instead be

```
Dog
Big Cat
Little Cat
Fat Cat
Orange Cat
Mouse
Bear
```

I've tried the below and its giving me an error of no matching signature

```
SELECT 
  IF(animal != 'Cat', animal, (SELECT AS STRUCT number_text_one, number_text_two, number_text_three, number_text_four from example_cat_table))
```

The 1-2-3-4 is just an example not to be used literally.

Is there a way this is possible?

Comment: Under what conditions would Cat appear, but ***not*** be replaced with Big/Little/Fat/Orange?  I also assume that maintaining the order matters?  In which case, how was the original order determined?

Comment: In this scenario there are thousands of potential replacements, ive just listed four as an example. 

The original order is sorted from a previous CTE, but as long as 'cat' shows up in the resulting query I would like any of the matching conditions appear.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select type || Animal as Animal 
from your_table
left join unnest(if(animal = 'Cat', ['Big ', 'Little ', 'Fat ', 'Orange '], [''] )) type
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: I would need the 'big' 'little' etc to be coming from another table, they are variable names that can have changing string values not static as 'big' 'little' etc

Comment: sure. this makes sense. but as your question is missing all these details - i gave you the hint - "just do left join" to whatever another table or data you have :o)

Answer (score 0):

You subsequently say there are many replacements that would be required, so I presume they'd be in a table similar to this...

| parent_animal | replacement_animal | replacement_order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cat | Big Cat | 1 |
| Cat | Little Cat | 2 |
| Cat | Fat Cat | 3 |
| Cat | Orange Cat | 4 |
| Unicorn | Mythical Beast | 1 |
| Unicorn | Narwhal | 2 |

Then you just need a `LEFT JOIN` and a `COALESCE()`, plus one addition to the `ORDER BY`...

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(replacement.replacement_animal, original.animal)  AS animal
FROM
  original
LEFT JOIN
  replacement
    ON original.animal = replacement.parent_animal
ORDER BY
  original.ordering_column,
  replacement.replacement_order
```